# Tensorflow model accuracy 0

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I am just starting out with Tensorflow. I am not encountering any errors but the model's accuracy is very low so something is going wrong somewhere. To ensure the complexity is as low as possible, I created a very small set of Principal, Rate , Time ... Interest column is my output. All values are numeric and correct, graph plot on raw data is correct so are shuffled test and training samples. Will appreciate if you can guide me where I am going wrong with this as have spent a lot of time around this.

sample
Principal   Rate    Time    Interest
1000    8   10  800
2000    7   5   700
3000    6   20  3600
1020    8   2   163
2030    7   4   568
4050    6   3   729
30      6.5 5   10
100     6   1   6
sample screenshot
[enter image description here][1]
The code is below

```
#import the basic stuff
#import csv from google drive 
data_df = pd.read_csv(filepath_or_buffer="/content/gdrive/My Drive/datasci/Interest.csv")
data_df.head()

# here split the data into train and test data 
train, test = train_test_split(data_df, test_size=0.2)
train, val = train_test_split(train, test_size=0.2)

def df_to_dataset(dataframe, shuffle=True, batch_size=32):
  dataframe = dataframe.copy()
  labels = dataframe.pop('Interest')
  ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((dict(dataframe), labels))
  if shuffle:
    ds = ds.shuffle(buffer_size=len(dataframe))
  ds = ds.batch(batch_size)
  return ds

batch_size = 6
train_ds = df_to_dataset(train, batch_size=batch_size)
val_ds = df_to_dataset(val, shuffle=False, batch_size=batch_size)
test_ds = df_to_dataset(test, shuffle=False, batch_size=batch_size)

NUMERIC_FEATURES = ['Principal',    'Rate', 'Time']
numeric_column = tf.feature_column.numeric_column('numeric',  shape=[len(NUMERIC_FEATURES)])
numeric_columns = [numeric_column]
numeric_column

class PackNumericFeatures(object):
  def __init__(self, names):
    self.names = names

  def __call__(self, features, labels):
    numeric_features = [features.pop(name) for name in self.names]
    numeric_features = [tf.cast(feat, tf.int16) for feat in numeric_features]
    numeric_features = tf.stack(numeric_features, axis=-1)
    features['numeric'] = numeric_features

    return features, labels

packed_train_data = train_ds.map(
    PackNumericFeatures(NUMERIC_FEATURES))

packed_test_data = test_ds.map(
    PackNumericFeatures(NUMERIC_FEATURES))
packed_val_data=val_ds.map( PackNumericFeatures(NUMERIC_FEATURES))

preprocessing_layer = tf.keras.layers.DenseFeatures(numeric_columns)

model = tf.keras.Sequential([
  preprocessing_layer,
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(1),
])

model.compile(optimizer='adam',loss=tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=True),metrics=['accuracy'])

train_data = packed_train_data.shuffle(500)
test_data = packed_test_data
val_data=packed_val_data

model.fit(train_data,validation_data=test_data,epochs=5)



>   
>     
>     output - 4/4 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: -1693.4762 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
>     <tensorflow.python.keras.callbacks.History at 0x7f6cf96f1828>
```

Comment: can you add the model summary?

Comment: When you say "*very small set*", how small? How many samples?

Comment: 60 samples, screenshot added